# Can you force a vassal to re-spawn?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

The Nord king seems to have disappeared and will not return (for several months now).  His vassals mostly sit around doing nothing and they always say they don't know where the king is.  Is there any way to force him to respawn?  A cheat or console command maybe?

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilies.

1. The King Ragnar (The Nord king) has gone into exile because he has no more territory.
2. The King has been taken prisoner and not yet been ransomed off.
3. He's been put in a castle and not been released for an unrealistic amount of time.

Your situation is very weird, normally a king is ransomed off fast because his family will pay a lot of money to get him back on the field. To my knowledge there is no cheat to get him back on the field/no way to force him to respawn

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion is looking in every castle and town in the prisonnier section for the factions you're at war against.